# Ubuntu XFCE 18.04 alternative to win32gui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu-18.04, win32gui

I have written some code in the windows environment using win32gui, and now I am trying to port it to be able to run on a machine running Ubuntu XFCE 18.04. Essentially I want to grab a specific window by its name, bring it into focus, and then get it's coordinates. Is there anything like this that works for ubuntu?

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
x, y, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
x, y = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd, (x, y))
```

Comment: That depends on which window manager / gui is being used

Comment: @planetmaker using XFCE, X11

Comment: If you want to do that from a _shell script_, your choice is `xdotool`.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the [X11 Window System](https://www.x.org/wiki/) which is more or less the standard windowing system used in Linux based graphical operating systems. It is not recommended to develop directly with X11 but rather to use a graphical toolkit such as Qt or GTK+, according to x.org themselves. However, if you wish to program directly with X11, you can use Xlib or X C bindings. You can find an assortment of documentation on these libraries at https://www.x.org/wiki/ProgrammingDocumentation/.

Comment: Yes, likely the win32gui level is accessible in [Xlib](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/). Don't expect the same level of completeness and logical neatness as in win32gui (no irony here, only sadness). There are reasonably nice Python bindings, too.